# Seaborn legend generated with hue breaks on melted dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

### Problem

I have following problem (which occured when I was trying to work on some melted df's). The problem is that when I am trying to manually set labels to melted df there appears to be one additional "shadow" legend entry which offsets all my labels by one.

### Steps reproduce

For example when I do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.random.random(100)
df['y1'] = np.random.random(100)
df['y2'] = np.random.random(100)
df['y3'] = np.random.random(100)
```

Then melt it:
df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars='x', value_vars=['y1', 'y2', 'y3'])
Which results in something like:

| x | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.454 | y1 | 0.846 |
| 0.654 | y2 | 0.487 |
| 0.741 | y3 | 0.653 |

When I try to plot it with:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.scatterplot(data=df_melted, x='x', y='value', hue='variable', ax=ax)
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ax.legend(title='my plot', labels=labels)
```

### Unexpected (problematic) result

I get following plot:

[image]

where 'a' and 'b' labels are for the same color (but different size?).

### Expected result

Expected result is more like plot for the following dataframe:

```
control_df = df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.random.random(100)
df['y'] = np.random.random(100)
df['group'] = np.random.randint(0,3,100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.scatterplot(data=control_df, x='x', y='y', hue='group', ax=ax)
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ax.legend(title='my plot', labels=labels)
```

Where I get (color palette does not matter):

[image]

### Question

What causes unexpected behaviour on melted dataframe before remapping? Number of columns is the same so where the additional legend entry comes from?

### Versions

- Pandas: 2.0.3
- Matplotlib: 3.7.2
- Seaborn: 0.12.2

Answer (score 0):

### Easy fix

Easy fix is to just remap column entries:

```
mask = {
    'y1': 'a',
    'y2': 'b',
    'y3': 'c'
}
df_melted2 = df_melted.replace({'variable': mask})
```

Then plot is as expected.

But it still does not answer the unexpected behaviour with original plot so anyone have any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74886914 may be useful, especially the portion "How to rename the legend entries." IIRC the behavior you're seeing is an artifact of how seaborn handles `hue`, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Seaborn often doesn't work well with `plt.legend()`.  For example, `scatterplot` without `hue_order` (and without the hue column explicitly being `pd.Categorical`) takes the order in which the values appear in the column.  This is not necessarily the order in which you want to provide the labels.  The strongly recommended approach, is to rename the hue values, as is correctly done in the current answer.  In general, due to the many options of a.o. `hue` and `style` and their combinations, seaborn creates its own specific legend.